# Port size (12 or 12) does not match connection size (6)

Tags: verilog, modelsim

*Booth algorithm is a multiplication operation that multiplies two numbers in two complement notation*

*The Booth multiplier has been widely used for high performance signed multiplication by encoding and thereby reducing the number of partial products*

May I know how to modify my Verilog coding as below because get the error message:

> Port size (12 or 12) does not match connection size (6)

```
module alu(out, in1, in2);

input [5:0] in1;
input [5:0] in2;
output [11:0] out;

assign out = in1 + in2; 

endmodule

module booth(out, in1, in2, clk, start);

parameter width = 6;
input clk, start;
input [5:0] in1;            //multiplicand
input [5:0] in2;            //multiplier
output [11:0] out;          //product

reg [5:0] A, Q, M;
reg Q_1; 
reg count;

wire[5:0] sum, difference;

always @(posedge clk)
begin
  if (start) begin
  A <= 6'b0;
  M <= in1;
  Q <= in2;    
  Q_1 <= 1'b0;
  count <= 2'b0;
end
else begin
  case ({Q[0], Q_1})
    2'b0_1: {A, Q, Q_1} <= {sum[5], sum, Q};
    2'b1_0: {A, Q, Q_1} <= {difference[5], difference, Q};
    default: {A, Q, Q_1} <= {A[5], A, Q};
    endcase
    count <= count + 1'b1;
end
end

alu adder (sum, A, M);
alu subtracter (difference, A, ~M);

assign out = {A, Q};

endmodule


`timescale 1ns / 10ps
`define CYCLE 30

  module booth_tb;
  parameter width = 6;
  
  wire [2*width-1:0] out;
  reg [width-1:0] in1;
  reg [width-1:0] in2;
  reg clk, start;
  
  integer num = 1;
  integer i;
  integer j;
  integer ans;
  integer err = 0;
  
  booth booth(.out(out), .in1(in1), .in2(in2), .clk, .start);
  
  initial begin
    for(i = (-(1<<width-1)+1); i < (1<<width-1); i = i+1) begin
      for(j = (-(1<<width-1)); j < (1<<width-1); j = j+1) begin
        in1 = i[width-1:0];
        in2 = j[width-1:0];
        #`CYCLE;
        ans = i * j;
        if(out == ans[2*width-1:0])
          $display("%d data is correct", num);
        else begin
          $display("%d data is error %b, correct is %b", num, out, ans[2*width-1:0]);
          err = err + 1;
        end
        num = num + 1;
      end
    end
    
    if(err == 0) begin
      $display("-------------------PASS-------------------");
      $display("All data have been generated successfully!");    
    end else begin
      $display("-------------------ERROR-------------------");
      $display("There are %d errors!", err);
    end
    
    #10 $finish;
  end 
endmodule
```

Answer (score 0):

If that was your exact error message, then it was not very specific.  You can try your code on other simulators if you sign up for a free account on edaplayground.  You might get more specific messages.

When I compile your code with VCS, I get a more helpful message:

```
Warning-[PCWM-W] Port connection width mismatch
"alu adder(sum, A, M);"
  The following 6-bit expression is connected to 12-bit port "out" of module 
  "alu", instance "adder".
  Expression: sum
```

This clearly shows your connection mistake.  You should only connect signals of the same width together.  For example, you could change:

```
wire[5:0] sum, difference;
```

to:

```
wire[11:0] sum, difference;
```

That gets rid of the compile warnings for me, but you need to decide what the proper width should be for these signals.